# POSTGRESQL FORMULA HELP WANTED

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsp

My Data is taken as table from PostGreSQL. It consists of 1024 rows and 2 columns  This is the sample table

```
wv1           rv1
341.6         2.48
343.6         2.58
344.7         2.37
346.3         2.32
347.9         2.29
349.5         2.36
351.1         2.23
352.6         2.24
354.2         2.25
355.8         2.29
357.4         2.28
358.9         2.23
```

I selected the data where wv1 between 341 and 359 from PostGreSQL Using

```
SELECT wv1 FROM grassland1 WHERE wv1 BETWEEN 341 AND 359
```

I am applying this formula in the selected data

```
The formula is **CRi=rv1i/(rv1START+K.(wv1i-wv1START))**
**K=(rv1END-rv1START)/(wv1END-wv1START)**
That is
rv1i - The current rv1 value
wv1i - Tha current wv1 value
rv1START - First value of rv1
rvlEND - last value of rv1
wv1START - First value of wv1
wvlEND - last value of wv1
```

**Steps**

**Steps for Numerator**

- The current rv1 value as rvi

**Steps for Denaminator**

- Subraction of rv1 Starting value and rv1 ending Value as
  rv1END-rv1START(ie., 2.23-2.48)
- Subraction of wv1 Starting value and wv1 ending Value as
  wv1END-wv1START(ie., 358.9-341.6)
- Divde (rv1END-rv1START)/(wv1END-wv1START)(ie., (2.23-2.48)/(358.9-341.6))
  and name the value as K
- Subraction of wv1i-wv1START (i.e., i=341.6,343.6,344.7,...) and
  multiply it with K Value as K.(wv1i-wv1START)
- Add Starting value of rvl with K.(wv1i-wv1START) as
  rv1START+K.(wv1i-wv1START) and name it as rv1

**Numerator/Denaminator**

- CRi=rv1i/(rv1START+K.(wv1i-wv1START))

My output will be like this

```
 wv1           rv1
341.6         1
343.6         1.049496
344.7         0.973225
346.3         0.961825
347.9         0.958576
349.5         0.955264
351.1         0.951886
352.6         0.965084
354.2         0.979147
355.8         1.006683
357.4         1.012579
358.9         1
```

This is the PostGreSQL query for tis task

```
DECLARE @rvlEND decimal, @rv1START decimal, @wv1END decimal, @wv1START decimal
    , @K decimal;

SET @wv1START = (SELECT MIN(wv1) FROM grassland1 
           WHERE wv1 BETWEEN 341 AND 359);
SET @wv1END = (SELECT MAX(wv1) FROM grassland1 
           WHERE wv1 BETWEEN 341 AND 359);
SET @rv1START = (SELECT rv1 FROM grassland1
           WHERE wv1 = @wv1START);
SET @rvlEND = (SELECT rv1 FROM grassland1 
           WHERE wv1 = @wv1END);

SET @K = (@rv1END - @rv1START)/(@wv1END - @wv1START);
```

Now that all the variables have been calculated, to evaluate the value of each row.

```
SELECT t.wv1,
    t.rv1/(@rv1START + (@K*(t.wv1 - @wv1START))) as CRi
FROM grassland1 t
WHERE wv1 BETWEEN 341-359
```

I dont know how to see the received output of the query, If not possible how i can do this in jsp...

Comment: @vmvadivel Sir,How to write this query as a procedure or function, then how i will see the ouput in PostGreSQL run

Comment: @Arnaud ALLAVENA,Sir,How to write this query as a procedure or function, then how i will see the ouput in PostGreSQL run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT wv1, rv1,
       rv1 / (rv1_first + ((rv1_last - rv1_first) / (wv1_last - wv1_first)) * (wv1 - wv1_first)) cri
  FROM
(
  SELECT wv1, rv1,
         FIRST_VALUE(wv1) OVER (ORDER BY wv1) wv1_first,
         FIRST_VALUE(wv1) OVER (ORDER BY wv1 DESC) wv1_last,
         FIRST_VALUE(rv1) OVER (ORDER BY wv1) rv1_first,
         FIRST_VALUE(rv1) OVER (ORDER BY wv1 DESC) rv1_last
    FROM grassland1
   WHERE wv1 BETWEEN 341 AND 359
) q
 ORDER BY wv1
```

Output:

```
|   WV1 |  RV1 |            CRI |
|-------|------|----------------|
| 341.6 | 2.48 |              1 |
| 343.6 | 2.58 | 1.052589378361 |
| 344.7 | 2.37 | 0.973225094353 |
| 346.3 | 2.32 | 0.961825109636 |
| 347.9 | 2.29 | 0.958576302354 |
| 349.5 | 2.36 | 0.997532312053 |
| 351.1 | 2.23 | 0.951886303634 |
| 352.6 | 2.24 | 0.965084424964 |
| 354.2 | 2.25 | 0.979146752528 |
| 355.8 | 2.29 | 1.006682929308 |
| 357.4 | 2.28 | 1.012578939262 |
| 358.9 | 2.23 |              1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1bcc7/8)** demo